# Captcha with Form trouble

Tags: php

I keep seeing if statements showing as text on the domain http://bambooflooringcapetown.net/recap.php

you can see for yourself.

I am trying to implement Securimage into my form but having troubles.

Captcha i am using:
http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/

Current Code:

```
     <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();

?>
<div>
    <?php
require_once 'securimage/securimage.php';
// Code Validation

$image = new Securimage();
if ($image->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == true) {
  echo "Correct!";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, wrong code.";
}
        require_once 'securimage/securimage.php';
        echo Securimage::getCaptchaHtml();
    ?>
</div>
<style>
#newheadform
{
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 361px;
    border: 1px solid #<?php echo $Config['bodyFontColour']; ?>;
    background-color: #<?php echo $Config['bodyColour']; ?>;
    color: #<?php echo $Config['bodyFontColour']; ?>;
    opacity: 0.85;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#newheadform input[type=text], #newheadform textarea
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 96%;
}
</style>
<!-- NEW ENQUIRY FORM START -->

<form method="post" action="">
<table id="newheadform" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="center"><font size="5">Email us now</font></th></tr>
        <tr><td>Name*:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone*:</td><td><input type="text" name="number"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email*:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">Message:</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="message" style="height: 50px;"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">Different Image</a>
        <?php if(isset($_POST['number']))
        {
            if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['number']) || empty($_POST['email']))
                echo '<font color="red" size="1"><b>* These fields are compulsory</b></font><br/><br/>';
            else
            {
                $headers='From: '.$_POST['email']."rn";
                $headers.='Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']."rn";
                $headers.='X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
                $body='You received a contact request from '.$_POST['name'].' ('.$_POST['email'].') on your site '.$domainname."rn";
                $body.='Contact number: '.$_POST['number']."rnrn";
                if(!empty($_POST['message'])) $body.=$_POST['message'];
                if(mail($_SESSION['contact3'],'New Enquiry from '.$domainname,$body,$headers))
                    echo '<font color="green"><b>Your email has been sent</b></font><br/>';
            }
        }
?>
                <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
        <input type="button" name="send" value="Send"/></td></tr>

</table>
</form>


<!-- NEW ENQUIRY FORM END -->
```

ORIGINAL CODE WITH NO CAPTCHA

```
    <!-- NEW ENQUIRY FORM START -->
<style>
#newheadform
{
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 361px;
    border: 1px solid #<?php echo $Config['bodyFontColour']; ?>;
    background-color: #<?php echo $Config['bodyColour']; ?>;
    color: #<?php echo $Config['bodyFontColour']; ?>;
    opacity: 0.85;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#newheadform input[type=text], #newheadform textarea
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 96%;
}
</style>
<form method="post" name="newheadformform">
    <table id="newheadform" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="center"><font size="5">Email us now</font></th></tr>
        <tr><td>Name*:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone*:</td><td><input type="text" name="number"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email*:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">Message:</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="message" style="height: 50px;"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
        <?php if(isset($_POST['number']))
        {
            if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['number']) || empty($_POST['email']))
                echo '<font color="red" size="1"><b>* These fields are compulsory</b></font><br/><br/>';
            else
            {
                $headers='From: '.$_POST['email']."rn";
                $headers.='Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']."rn";
                $headers.='X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
                $body='You received a contact request from '.$_POST['name'].' ('.$_POST['email'].') on your site '.$domainname."rn";
                $body.='Contact number: '.$_POST['number']."rnrn";
                if(!empty($_POST['message'])) $body.=$_POST['message'];
                if(mail($_SESSION['contact3'],'New Enquiry from '.$domainname,$body,$headers))
                    echo '<font color="green"><b>Your email has been sent</b></font><br/>';
            }
        }
        else echo '<font size="1">* Compulsory</font><br/><br/>'; ?>
    Calculate*: <span id="num1"></span> + <span id="num2"></span>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="calculate" placeholder="" /><br><br>
        <input type="button" name="send" value="Send"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12)+1;
    var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12)+1;

    $('#num1').append(number1);
    $('#num2').append(number2);

  $('input[name=send]').click(function(){

        var total = number1 + number2;
        var answer = $('input[name=calculate]').val();

        if(total !== parseInt(answer)){

            alert("Please enter the correct calculation to send your enquiry.");

        } else {

            document.newheadformform.submit(); 
            return false;

        }
    });
});
</script>
<!-- NEW ENQUIRY FORM END -->
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing CSS/HTML with PHP. Split them up.

Comment: Your PHP has to be wrapped in `<?php` tags. But like @Fred-ii- said it would be better if the PHP was in another file

Comment: how wouldi split them up? cuz it all came from the index.php

Comment: Shit everytime, i wrap anything new in <?php?> it breaks the entire page

Comment: It seems i have got a issue with form validation and general how to use both captcha and form to send

Comment: i get this now Notice: Undefined index: captcha_code in /usr/www/users/bamboxevvz/recap.php on line 13 Sorry, wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use the honeypot method.

Honeypot fields are invisible fields on the form. Invisible is different than hidden. Hidden is a type of field that is not displayed for editing. Bots understand hidden fields, because hidden fields often carry identifying information that has to be returned intact. Invisible fields are ordinary editable fields that have been made invisible in the browser.

The invisibility of the honeypot fields is a key way that bots reveal themselves. Because bots do not process the entirety of the HTML, CSS, and Javascript in the form, and because they do not build a visual representation of the page, and because they do not perceive the form as people do, they cannot distinguish invisible fields from visible ones. They will put data into honeypot fields because they don't know any better.

On the downside, if the bot-programmer somehow (manually?) recognizes your honeypot, and adjusts his bot to skip the honeypot field, then you're screwed. A captcha will force the bot-programmer to develop an Image Recognition application.

So while it's easier for the human, it's also easier for the bot.

You can also use a server side session variable that stores when the user first got to the form. Then you call that variable on your submit page.  If it's under a few seconds then chances are its a bot. This can work well because the bot has no idea whats going on at the server.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: captcha_code in /usr/www/users/bamboxevvz/recap.php on line 13 Sorry, wrong code.