# PHP email form shooting blank emails

Tags: php, forms, email

I put together a simple PHP email form for a website, but it keeps sending blank emails every so often. Most of the the fields are "required" and I was using a captcha system for a while, but the blank emails kept coming.

HTML markup:

```
<form action="mail_send.php" method="post">

<input name="name" type="text" required="required" size="40" />

<input name="email" type="text" required="required" size="40" />

<input name="company" type="text" size="40" />

<textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7" required="required"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" FROM:\n $name \n\n COMPANY:\n $company \n\n MESSAGE:\n $message";
$recipient = "email address";
$subject = "Subject";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo "<script>window.location = 'confirmation.php'</script>";
```

Everything works fine when I test it, I receive the emails from the form with no problems at all, but for some reason I keep getting blank emails often (possibly from robots).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the PHP page separate from the HTML page?  If so, a bot could just post to that URL without going through your form. I would suggest also doing validation server side as well.

Comment: @user2547075 The PHP is indeed separate.

Comment: I would suggest putting duplicate validation server side.  Never trust the client! :)

Comment: @user2547075 How would I do that?

Comment: I just posted an answer. Hope it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/a/35656086/2547075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could happen if your HTML form and PHP are inside the same file while  you're not checking if any of those inputs are empty or not. And if not in the same file, not checking for emptyness, still applies.

You could be the victim of bots, or some joker visiting your site ever so often just to tick you off.

Or that the form's method's URL is being accessed directly by someone or something, which is what I feel may be the issue here, since you do have `required` for your inputs.

- Check your access logs.

So, use a conditional `!empty()` against all your inputs.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I.e.:

Sidenote: `||` checks to see if one or any are empty.

```
if( !empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) ){

   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   // process mail

}
```

You can add the other ones in.

Or give your submit a name attribute:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Then check if the button is set and that the inputs are not empty:

```
if(isset(_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) ){

       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];

       // process mail

    }

}
```

---

You should also use filters, for the email input:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Plus, if you decide to use radios/checkboxes later on, use `isset()` against those.

**Sidenote:**

You could add a checkbox to your form to check if it was checked or not, and handle it with a conditional statement.

---

Footnotes:

> *"Most of the the fields are "required" and I was using a captcha system for a while, but the blank emails kept coming."*

There isn't any captcha code in your question to support this.

**N.B.:**

The required attribute only works in HTML5 supported browsers. Therefore, if any of those bots or visitors to your site are using a browser that doesn't support HTML5, or technology that can bypass it, then that too could be another (contributing) factor.

Comment: As stated in one of the answers comments, required attribute as displayed in the html code by the OP, is valid XHTML. (as long as it is defined in the doctype) Seeing the input elements on his form only solidifies this argument as in any other html type it should be closed with `</input>` over `/>`

Comment: @Xorifelse OP should be posting full code then and to show us how their doc declaration looks like. At this point, OP still hasn't commented anywhere, so it's anybody's game.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the response. I will implement your suggestions. The blank emails come in almost daily, if it stops for a day or two it probably worked.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do validation on your PHP.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Basically you will want to do the following:

**Security**

```
    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

**Validation**

```
if (!empty($email)){
    //your code to send email
}
```

You could make it a little more complex if you want to check more than one thing.

```
$fail_validation = FALSE;
if (empty($email)){
   $fail_validation = TRUE;

}
if (empty($phone)){
   $fail_validation = TRUE;

}
if ($fail_validation == FALSE){
  //code to send mail goes here
}
```

Please note, this is very basic, and you may want to consider looking into some extra functions to secure the PHP.  I would also suggest using a honeypot as an extra layer of security. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103646/2547075

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7" required="required"></textarea>
```

should be

```
<textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7" required></textarea>
```

Are you writing XHTML or HTML?

Validation on the server side is also recommended. See answers below on how to do it.

Comment: This is referring to a HTML error, php doesn't care about this. And even so, this is valid in xhtml 1.1.

Comment: He stated HTML. I would assume its html 5.

Comment: I would assume html 4.01 since I see no reference to any html 5 markup.

Comment: Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5
The required attribute is new in HTML5.

Comment: Alright, you are right. He is writing XHTML, not HTML

Comment: Still, you corrected me its not HTML 4.01. But hey, due the complexity of this already running script I'm still surprised its XHTML. But all comments aside, this answer still does not resolve his issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104479/discussion-between-an-overflowed-stack-and-xorifelse).

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason you're getting blank emails, possibly from robots

pretty much answered your question. Robots can be pretty advanced and break certain Captcha'a as well to post blank post requests. You should check if the post requests are not empty.

The unbreakable captcha's are the ones you've written yourself (and not spread be-hound your website until it becomes popular) or [the recently introduced one from Google](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html). give it a try (once you've checked for [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) values)

Comment: I tried the recaptcha from google, but it didn't prevent the blank emails from being sent. I will try your suggestion to check for empty values.